# how to use window.innerWidth within computed property - NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm working on a nuxt.js project, where I need to determine styles within the `computed` propety and apply on a `div` based on `screen size`, as in the example below:

basic example

```
<template>
  <div :style="css"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    css () {
      let width = window.innerWidth

      // ... mobile { ... styles }
      // ... desktop { ... styles }

      // ... if width is less than 700, return mobile
      // ... if width greater than 700, return desktop
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

real example

```
<template>
  <div :style="css">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    columns: String,
    rows: String,
    areas: String,
    gap: String,
    columnGap: String,
    rowGap: String,
    horizontalAlign: String,
    verticalAlign: String,
    small: Object,
    medium: Object,
    large: Object
  },
  computed: {
    css () {
      let small, medium, large, infinty

      large = this.generateGridStyles(this.large)
      medium = this.generateGridStyles(this.medium)
      small = this.generateGridStyles(this.small)
      infinty = this.generateGridStyles()

      if (this.mq() === 'small' && this.small) return Object.assign(infinty, small)

      if (this.mq() === 'medium' && this.medium) return Object.assign(infinty, medium)

      if (this.mq() === 'large' && this.large) return Object.assign(infinty, large)

      if (this.mq() === 'infinty') return infinty

    }
  },
  methods: {
    generateGridStyles (options) {
      return {
        'grid-template-columns': (options !== undefined) ? options.columns : this.columns,
        'grid-template-rows': (options !== undefined) ? options.rows : this.rows,
        'grid-template-areas': (options !== undefined) ? options.areas : this.areas,
        'grid-gap': (options !== undefined) ? options.gap : this.gap,
        'grid-column-gap': (options !== undefined) ? options.columnGap : this.columnGap,
        'grid-row-gap': (options !== undefined) ? options.rowGap : this.rowGap,
        'vertical-align': (options !== undefined) ? options.verticalAlign : this.verticalAlign,
        'horizontal-align': (options !== undefined) ? options.horizontalAlign : this.horizontalAlign,
      }
    },
    mq () {
      let width = window.innerWidth

      if (width < 600) return 'small'
      if (width > 600 && width < 992) return 'medium'
      if (width > 992 && width < 1200) return 'large'
      if (width > 1200) return 'infinty'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
div {
  display: grid;
}
</style>
```

making use of the `GridLayout` component on pages.vue

```
<template>
  <GridLayout
    columns="1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr"
    rows="auto"
    gap="10px"
    verital-align="center"
    :small="{
      columns: '1fr',
      rows: 'auto auto auto auto',
    }"
  >
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h1>2</h1>
    <h1>3</h1>
    <h1>3</h1>
  </GridLayout>
</template>

<script>
import { GridLayout } from '@/components/bosons'

export default {
  layout: 'blank',
  components: {
    GridLayout
  },
}
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
h1 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

> does not work, it generates a error `windows is note defined` in `if
>   (this.mq() === 'small')`

This works perfectly in `pure Vue.js` but I understand that it does not work on Nuxt.js because it is server side rendering, it makes perfect sense, but how could I make it work?

the closest I got was moving the style code into the `mounted` method or wrapping the style code in `if (process.client) {...}`, but any of the alternatives would generate a certain `delay`, `jump` in content, example:

[process.client  vs without the process.client](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJ5NNe8W_BKZY5j0rhsNd8J62EA0hAdD/view)

[jump / delay on the layout when uses process.client condition](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QINCA313K53YESV8e_k4nNqylWKZaqf-/view)

how could I make it work without delay? how could I have the screen width before the mounted, default behavior of Vue.js?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect it's because the Nuxt framework is attempting to compute it on the server-side where there is no window object. You need to make sure that it computes it in the browser by checking `process.client`:

```
export default {
  computed: {
    css () {
      if (process.client) {
        let width = window.innerWidth

        // ... mobile { ... styles }
        // ... desktop { ... styles }

        // ... if width is less than 700, return mobile
        // ... if width greater than 700, return desktop
      } else {
        return { /*empty style object*/ }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the delay, it's a little bit "hacky" but you could return null if `window` is not available and simply display once the computed property becomes available. You would still have a delay before it becomes visible, as the root of the problem is that the style is getting applied on the next DOM update.

```
<template>
    <div :style="css" v-show="css">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    css () {
      if (process.client) {
        let width = window.innerWidth

        // ... mobile { ... styles }
        // ... desktop { ... styles }

        // ... if width is less than 700, return mobile
        // ... if width greater than 700, return desktop
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Alternatively, as the css is applied on the next DOM update you could use a data property with Vue.$nextTick() (but it is essentially the same thing):

```
<template>
    <div :style="css" v-show="reveal">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      reveal: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    css () {
      if (process.client) {
        let width = window.innerWidth

        // ... mobile { ... styles }
        // ... desktop { ... styles }

        // ... if width is less than 700, return mobile
        // ... if width greater than 700, return desktop
      } else {
        return { /*empty style object*/ }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.reveal = true
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

However, from your question, it appears that you want to apply a responsive layout. The best approach would be to `scope` this into your `style` tags and use css breakpoints. This would solve the delay problem and decouple your style and logic.

```
<template>
    <div class="my-responsive-component">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: { /* nothing to see here! */ }
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
.my-responsive-component {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .my-responsive-component { background: yellow; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .my-responsive-component { background: cyan; }
}
</style>
```

Btw, just as a side note, use the proper if/else statement in full for computed properties. Using things like `if (!process.client) return { /* empty style object */}` sometimes produces some unexpected behaviour in Vue computed properties.

Comment: I tested it and it works, but it applies the style with a delay because of `if (process.client)`, same when the style logic is inside the `mountd` .. I need to have the styles ready before reaching the `mounted`.

I tried [this option](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1053#issuecomment-418340677) but the code seems incomplete, I could not get it to work, can you help me? I'm not using store, I'd like to store in a global function, for example `this.$mq`

Comment: From your question, it appears you just want to have a responsive layout. Your best option is to write the breakpoints into your css directly and not have the style dependent on a computed property... is this not an option for you?

There are other/better options but I'm not sure how your project is set up or what your aim is.

Comment: in this case no, because it is a reusable component, soon the stylization will be dynamic and will have a certain level of complexity to the point that only assigning a CSS class would not solve the problem, need to be done with scripting.

Comment: My gut says that this is not the right approach, but I don't know what you're building so I trust you! :)

Regarding the delay, I suppose you could just display once the computed property is set on the next tick... it's a little bit "hacky" but it might work. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I'm really happy to be helping me :)
I tested, it works again, but still with delay, only different.

If you only use `if (process.client)` it displays unstressed content, and applies the style with delay.

If use `if (process.client)` along with `v-show =" css "` it will show the div only when the style is ready, but still with delay compared to other div/DOM.

in short, the delay problem continues

Comment: I believe the best option is to check `innerWidth` inside the `computed` with the help of a [plugin injected into](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins#inject-in-root-amp-context) and [this](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1053#issuecomment-418340677),  the context, then simply do `if (this.$ mq < 600) return 'mobile'`

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that the div was a container of some sort. I believe the delay is because the css doesn't get applied until the next DOM update cycle, so I don't think injecting a global function will solve the delay problem. Ultimately, I think you'll have to do this via css (I'll edit my answer to include this)... maybe if you can show us your mobile/desktop css objects we can help you with that?

Comment: I updated my question, I'd love for you to take a look, can you imagine some way to solve it without having to delete the `GridLayout` component?

Comment: Yes, that is a little more complex! haha. Well, I quickly copied and pasted that into a new nuxt project and there is no issue with delay. Everything renders on time. I assume your real code is lot more complex and it doesn't get computed until the next tick. As a quick fix, I suppose you could; 1) Add an inline placeholder until v-show is ready; or 2) Don't show any components on the page until the computed innerWidth is ready... maybe pass innerWidth as a prop to GridLayout? Sorry it's a bit hacky and I can't be of more help here... but that's my 2 cents given I can't reproduce the delay.

Comment: When i updated my question i put `if (this.mq === 'small')` but the correct one is `if (this.mq() === 'small')`, I updated my question again! if you copy and run in a nuxt project, you will see that the `window is not defined` error.

if you wrap everything inside an `if (process.client)` you will see the delay regardless of the complexity or size of the page.

Comment: Ok, I wrapped everything in process.client. I'm resizing my window width small, medium etc. but I still don't get a delay.

Comment: the delay is only on the first load of the component, do a simple test [with process.client](https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/gVbdNa) and another test [without process.client](https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/QewZLv), will observe that when it has the condition (process.cliente) it takes a while to apply the styles

Comment: to observe more clearly, keep pressing `F5` or `command + R` if it is on the mac

Comment: I'm doing exactly that... honestly I have no delay. I'm using Nuxt v2.8.1. I've disabled cache.

Comment: [look this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AJ5NNe8W_BKZY5j0rhsNd8J62EA0hAdD/view), can you upload a video too? I'd like to see the behavior you're getting, I know it sounds like little, but this little delay in big things can make the site very ugly.

Comment: `(process.client)` being applied to `GridLayout.vue` [see the delay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QINCA313K53YESV8e_k4nNqylWKZaqf-/view)

Comment: Ah yes, I can reproduce it now! The problem was I wasn't doing it in 'infinty', apologies. Yes, this is definitely because it doesn't update until the next DOM update cycle. So with this implementation a quick fix would be to apply v-show on Vue.$nextTick or by waiting until non-falsy value for css like in my answer. Both will produce a tiny delay but at least the user won't see the layout jump.

Comment: could you show me the nextTick sweat in this situation?

Comment: sure, I've updated my answer. But it essentially the same as css != null solution before. I'm just writing it directly on my phone so there might be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old issue which is happening due to server rendering, as stated in below issue on github.

**.vue file**

```
<script>
if (process.browser) {
  require('aframe')
}
export default {

}
</script>
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  build: {
    vendor: ['aframe']
  }
```

**Reference:**
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/30#issuecomment-264348589
https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/